# Dictionary service free online

Tags: web-services, rest

Anyone knows a good FREE dictionary service? I want to consume it through HTTP Get and then parsing simple HTML or Json.

Dictionary.com is free for non commercial purposes. I need something completely free and reliable.

Comment: This question shouldnt have been closed, as I am consuming those services from a Rails application parsing json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google used to have a good api but thy have since changed it to a paid service.
Wordnik API might be usefull http://developer.wordnik.com/docs

It requires a registration, but it supports a bunch of cool features, such as word audio, and you can easily find client libraries for that in different programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

The okapi framework offers a set of translation connectors. Take a look:
http://www.opentag.com/okapi/wiki/index.php?title=Connectors

Not sure about the licenses for those services they are using - but some of them might be just what you need. (click on each connector to read about the webservice it is based on)